# rebar3 can't load compiled files

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, elixir, rebar3

I have used reabr3 to create an application to practice the RabbitMQ but the rebar3 can not load the additional file I created in the `src` folder to erlang shell.

I used `rebar3 new app rabbit`. I had `rabbit_app.erl rabbit_sup.erl and rabbit.app.src` and a new defined file named `hello_world.erl` in the `src/` directory. I ran the `rebar3 compile` to compile and get dependencies.

Then ran `rebar3 shell` to able to test the function in `hello_world.erl`. The `hello_world.beam` can not be loaded so I have to use the `c(hello_world)` manually in erlang shell. It is a bit inconvenient.

Any helps would highly be appreciated. Here is the console output for `rebar3 compile` and `rebar3 shell`.

```
$ rebar3 compile
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Fetching amqp_client v3.8.14
===> Fetching rabbit_common v3.8.7
===> Fetching credentials_obfuscation v2.2.0
===> Fetching jsx v2.11.0
===> Fetching lager v3.8.0
===> Fetching ranch v1.7.1
===> Fetching recon v2.5.1
===> Fetching goldrush v0.1.9
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling credentials_obfuscation
===> Compiling goldrush
===> Compiling jsx
===> Compiling lager
===> Compiling ranch
===> Compiling recon
===> Compiling rabbit_common
===> Compiling amqp_client
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling rabbit

$ rebar3 shell
===> Verifying dependencies...
===> Analyzing applications...
===> Compiling rabbit
Erlang/OTP 22 [erts-10.7.2.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:16:16] [ds:16:16:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Eshell V10.7.2.1  (abort with ^G)
1> ===> Booted xmerl
===> Booted compiler
===> Booted sasl
===> Booted syntax_tools
===> Booted tools
===> Booted goldrush
===> Booted lager
===> Booted jsx
===> Booted ranch
===> Booted recon
===> Booted credentials_obfuscation
===> Booted rabbit_common
===> Booted amqp_client
===> Booted rabbit
```

[UPDATE] I found that the new added files were load but the auto-complete for these files did not work. I had to use the whole command for the first time.

Comment: instead of c(hello_world)., try r3:compile().

Comment: it works for now. Thank you! Could you explain what behind this command? I saw it also compiled my `rabbit` application. Did it also load the beam files to Erlang shell?

Comment: You should find all that info and more here: https://ferd.ca/rebar3-shell.html

Answer (score 0):

`rebar3` organizes the `.beam` files in directories outside the `src` directory.  When you issue the command `c(hello_world)`, the `.beam` file is placed in the current directory.  Apparently, you are issuing your `rebar3` commands while the current directory is the `src/` directory, which is not the way things are done with `rebar3`.  You need to be in the `rabbit/` directory, i.e. the top level directory of your `app`, when you issue `rebar3` commands like `rebar3 compile` and `rebar3 shell`.

Comment: Yes, I was in the `rabbit/` directory when I issued the `rebar3 compile and rebar3 shell`. I could see the `_build/default/lib/rabbit/ebin/hello_world.beam`. But I am not able to call `hello_world` module in the shell.

Comment: @tandathuynh148, Show your command line commands, shell commands, and output.  By that, I don't mean that you should describe what you did, instead post the actual commands and output, starting with creating the app.

Comment: Thank you so much. You can find the output of the commands here: https://imgur.com/Y8rZOMZ and https://imgur.com/aSFrFN2

Comment: @tandathuynh148, could you also check if `hello_world` is listed in `modules` list of `_build/default/lib/rabbit/ebin/rabbit.app` file? Also what version of `rebar3` are you using?

Comment: @tandathuynh148, Sorry, that isn't the way things are done on stackoverflow.  Copy and paste your commands and output and post them at the bottom of your question.  Linking to images is terrible form--and don't post images either.

Comment: Hi @7stud, I have updated the console output.

Hi @VenkatakumarSrinivasan, the `hello_world` was listed in the modules of `rabbit.app`

Comment: @tandathuynh148, The output you posted does not match what you described above the output.  Try this: create a new app called `rabbit2`, then add hello_world.erl to the `src/` directory.  Then change directories back to the top level rabbit2 directory, then issue the command `rebar3 compile`, then `rebar3 shell`.  Does calling a function defined in hello_world.erl work now?

Comment: Hi @7stud, I just found that it worked. But the auto-complete when I type the command prefix did not work, I have to type the whole command